# Force required with an electromagnet to equal 6300 force pounds to run an typical v8 combustion engine

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I want to know if i have a strong rare earth magnet attached to top of an aluminum piston in a typical v8 combustion engine with an electromagnet at top of piston chamber instead of a spark plug "taking into account everything else needed to make this work has been done" how much power size of electromagnet, would be needed to produce same amount of force 6300 pounds to get the engine going? The magnets can both repel and attract if need be.
Is this possible? 14679.1314 newtons = 6300lbf
28035 newtons = 6300lbs

Answer (score 1):

You are basically describing a solenoid engine, these are quite functional, and could probably be made large enough to propel a full sized car. Although not a very energy efficient, or smooth operating design for an electric motor. Here is a video link to a small 4 solenoid engine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4im3M9IFcI If you type in "solenoid engine" in their search line, you will find many more of  different designs. The main problem with the design you describe, is that the magnetic force would be very weak when the piston was at the bottom of the stroke. You would only have a strong magnetic force toward the top of the stroke. This is because a magnetic force drops off sharply with distance. There are more efficient solenoid designs.

Comment: Thank you very cool and similar save for i want to literally take a closed engine with compression that currently runs off of fuel and convert it with very few changes. Provided at just about top dead center where combustion currently takes place. However instead of cumbustion rapidly fire off a sudden powerful bust from the electromagnet that is opposite pole of the powerful rare earth magnet powerful enough to provide the 6300 lbs needed to get engine going. Each piston has its own set of magnets and capacitors for storing and firing off the electromagnet under current

Comment: timing of a normal combustion engine. Use what we know works with a different sorce of force.

Comment: @KingDraykal A short stroke v8 or v6 might work best n that case, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have some of the ideas right. Magnetic forces are what makes an [electric motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motor) run. But things are usually arranged differently.

You are suggesting using an electromagnet to push and pull a magnetic piston. Then the car's crankshaft will convert back and forth motion to rotary motion. It is more common to arrange magnets and electromagnets so they directly rotate.

It is possible to make an electric motor strong enough to run a car.

Usually electric cars are smaller than cars that use a V8 engine. Perhaps this is because an electric car needs a lot of heavy batteries, and smaller means less batteries. Perhaps it is because electric cars appeal to people that want economic cars. But a bigger electric car could be made.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I dont want it to end up as a electric motor. I want it to stay under compression, use what we know works. We know these combustion egines have the power people want.

Comment: So change the element that provides the 6300 lb force needed to turn motor. Since magnets push away shouldnt we be able to fire off at tge right moment enough power into an electromagnet at top of combustion chamber opposite of the fixed rare earth magnet to acomplish this?

Comment: Compression in a cylinder ls like a spring. It takes energy to push the cylinder to compress gas, and you get the energy back again when the gas pushes the cylinder back. If you compress a fuel/air mixture, you can burn it and extract more energy by letting the hot gases push. If you are using magnets instead of burning fuel, there is no reason to have compression.

Comment: You question is getting into engineering. Physics is all about how current generates magnetic fields and how magnetic fields generate forces. This makes an electric motor possible. Engineering takes into account things like magnetic fields get weak away from the solenoid. Engineers figure out how to make a motor that works well. Try this question at https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.